# Installing libgtk-3-dev on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, apt

How can I install Libgtk-3-dev on Ubuntu 10.04? If I try `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev` I get Couldn't find Package. It's not a typo and it's in correctly so I have no idea where to go. Not going to upgrade. I cannot stand the distro's after 10.04. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: If you're not upgrading, I see little utility in the package.  Either way the dev sources are available here: http://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php

Comment: Thanks. It's simply because some packages need it for compiliation. Kind of stupid to require it for packages that would otherwise run easily in 10.04, but I'm opinionated about it. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package is not available for ubuntu 10.04,It is the development libraries of GTk3 whereas 10.04 is a Gtk2 distro, So you can't install it in 10.04